# Access VBA read the current recordset position?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to save data from a selected recordset field, but I just save the first record. (Vorname, db and rs are public variables) [Vorname] is the column name in the recordset. The query is showed in a subform.

The Code:

```
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Kontaktabfrage", dbOpenDynaset)
Vorname = rs![Vorname]
Me.Refresh
```

I want to get the selected record. Example:

```
ID| Vorname
1   John
2   Will
3   Stan
```

When I select Will in the subform, the recordset gives me John, because he is the first record, but I want Will. How can I read out that property?

Answer (score 0):

Use the *RecordsetClone* of the form:

```
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
' or, if in a subform:
' Set rs = Me.SubformControlNAME.Form.RecordsetClone

' Position the recordset to match the current record of the form.
rs.Bookmark = Me.Bookmark
' or, if in a subform:
' rs.Bookmark = Me.SubformControlNAME.Form.Bookmark

Vorname = rs![Vorname].Value
```

Comment: It's not a method, it's the name of your subform _control_ - if that is what you have.